# Sublime Text 2: soft wrap lines -> reverse indentation?

Tags: sublimetext2

I've started using Sublime Text 2, and its community of plugins, as my Dreamweaver replacement (thank the Gods). I love Sublime and clearly won't realize many of its features for months or years to come, but there's a simple setting I've had trouble figuring out.

I've used BBedit lots in the past. One feature I'm very attached to is the ability to "reverse" indent lines when soft-wrapped, such that line wrapping looks like this:

```
Text text blah blah blah blah long enough to wrap
  to a new line blah whenever soft wrap happens it
  reverse-indents like this.
Here's a new line with no indent.
```

Maybe I shouldn't be so married to a seemingly minor feature, but I find it much easier to read code when it's not possible to confuse the beginning of a line with "tailings" of a long line. Does anyone know how to do this in Sublime?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I'd suggest enabling line numbering and using a theme with current-line-highlight - see http://screencloud.net/v/o01L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further use, I think I've figured this out. Apparently Sublime's default (and only) behavior is to reverse-indent *code* lines, but leave *html* lines flush. So when I'm editing a PHP/HTML document, my wrapped lines will reverse-indent about half the time, depending on whether I'm in an  tag or in a  fragment at that line break.

The effect on my code is something like this:

```
<!-- Wrapped HTML doesn't reverse indent -->
<a href='long_link_that_causes_lines_to_wrap' other_attribute='
jquery_thing_that_makes_lines_wrap'>something</a>
...
<!-- Wrapped PHP snippets do reverse indent -->
<? echo date('M jS', strtotime('some_interpolated_formatting_string', 
  $some_variable_expression)); ?>
```

Comment: How frustratingly useless, Sublime -- what kind of crap logic is this? What a glaringly arbitrary inconsistency -- the worst kind of inconsistency. Stuck with the same problem..

Comment: ChaseMoskal, I hear you. It's a strange pattern, especially given that you have no control over it. But to be honest, over the past year of use (and using word wrap the entire time), this inconsistency has not caused problem beyond my initial confusion last summer.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime uses JSON files to store your preferences. The default file lists the settings that it uses by default, and you can override them by adding them to your user file.

The preference that controls hanging indent is `word_wrap`:

```
// Disables horizontal scrolling if enabled.
// May be set to true, false, or "auto", where it will be disabled for
// source code, and otherwise enabled.
"word_wrap": "auto",
```

As shown above, the default value is `auto` which only wraps lines that are not considered source code. To get hanging indent on all lines in a file, you need to set it to `true` in your user preferences file:

```
"word_wrap": true,
```